# Qual é a ordem correta para injetar dependencias nos controllers Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, psr

Tenho notado que as vezes, dependendo da ordem que eu injeto as dependencias, elas não funcionam...

Existe alguma ordem correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ***construtor***, pode ser resolvido qualquer dependência e não tem uma ordem, mas, quando a resolução é feita pela métodos a ordem é em relação aos parâmetros de rotas, que sempre serão depois de todas as dependências que precisam ser resolvidas, ***exemplo***:

***Rota:***

```
Route::post('save/{id}', 'AdminController@save');
Route::post('view/{id}/{slug}', 'NoticeController@view');
```

***Método:***

```
public function save(Request $request, $id)
{
}
```

---

```
public function view(Request $request, RepositoryNotice $repository, $id, $slug)
{
}
```

então, os paramentos de rotas sempre são colocados no final do método, [explicação está na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)

<sub>***Referencias*** [Dependency Injection & Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)</sub>